# detectando movimentos utilizando onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, xml

encontrei este método na internet para detectar movimento, porém eu gostaria quando movesse para direita executa um comando (*exemplo mudasse a cor do botão*), mas estou com dificuldades de implementar este código se alguém souber para me dar um força, agradeço desde já.

```
private String TAG = GestureActivity.class.getSimpleName();
float initialX, initialY;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    int action = event.getActionMasked();

    switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = event.getX();
            initialY = event.getY();

            Log.d(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d(TAG, "Action was MOVE");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float finalX = event.getX();
            float finalY = event.getY();

            Log.d(TAG, "Action was UP");

            if (initialX < finalX) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
            }

            if (initialX > finalX) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
            }

            if (initialY < finalY) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
            }

            if (initialY > finalY) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.d(TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            Log.d(TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
            break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Rodolfo, você poderia descrever sua dificuldade? No seu código, "mover para a direita" é o primeiro `if` (você pode substituir `Log.d(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");` pelo código para mudar a cor do botão ou o que quiser.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua questão. Conforme o que eu entendi, acho que este link irá sanar suas dúvidas:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645537/how-to-detect-the-swipe-left-or-right-in-android Boa sorte!

Comment: A primeira linha usa reflexão para pegar o nome da classe `GestureActivity`. O parâmetro [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) é um evento contendo a posição atual e dados históricos do movimento. Você deve sobrescrever esse método `onTouchEvent`em uma `Activity` ou criar e atrelar um [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) à sua view. Ela por sua vez irá criar o evento e disparar para seu `listener`.

Comment: Para ajuda mais concreta (para colocar seu código para funcionar), sugiro que você crie um [mvce](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) apontando exatamente onde estão suas dúvidas.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly funcionou código, porém  ele não funciona na primeira e preciso fazer varias tentativas.

Comment: se você souber outro método para esse fim, e puder me ajudar

Comment: Rodolfo, minha sugestão é usar o `GestureDetector` junto com o `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`, podendo detectar o gesto pelo `onFling` e/ou o `onScroll`, verificando o deslocamento na coordenada y.